# Creating my own sdk to be used with other iOS apps

Tags: ios

I have released an app in app-store. It shows the visual IVR navigation sequence of different customer care and connects the call to appropriate option. The first screen is collectionView where it shows all the customer cares. On selecting any customer care it opens visual Ivr navigation sequence for that customer care. Now I want to build it as a SDK which can be integrated with other iOS apps.

For e.g.:

> Suppose ICICI bank wants to integrate it with their app.So I want to build it in a way such that they can easily integrate it in their app as a SDK. Also instead of showing all the customer care, it will just show the visual ivr navigation sequence of ICICI bank only.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you create a libraries .a more than an SDK as the MVC structure used by the bank app may be complex and hence a isolated control and interfaces to use the features will be more helpful.

Lets say in your above example you can expose features like

1) Configuring the amount of services for call centers
2) CRUD Feature for the services exposed.
3) Delegates and Protocol methods for callbacks and datasource handling.
4) Execution reports and analytics, etc...many more things you can expose and keep library growing.

Hope that answers your question.